# Overlaying Text in VLC using WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, vlc

I am creating a program that displays song lyrics using WPF. I want to use videos as the background(using VLC player). How can I overlay the lyrics over the video background?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be possible directly in WPF. I assume that you would need a WinformsHost  to host the VLC player. It's a known issue(limitation) that WPF controls and winforms can't share the same screen area(airspace limitation). However there are many workarounds for this limitation, one of them being adding 2 WPF windows overlayed.

Alternatively you can try upgrading to WPF 4.5(Using VS-2012), this issue seems to b e fixed there.

Read:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970688(v=vs.100).aspx

http://bartwullems.blogspot.in/2010/11/wpf-and-winforms-airspace-problem.html?m=1